# Class does not exist in current context in asp.net

Tags: .net

I am getting this error I want to use another class method.I am doing asp.net project.Please Help!!

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'printHelper' does not exist in the current context

```
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web.SessionState;


printHelper.cs
namespace C2Project
{
    public class printHelper
    {

       public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl)
       {
            PrintWebControl(ctrl, string.Empty);
       }
      . . .
    }
}
```

In another webForm
print.aspx.cs

```
public partial class Print : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Control ctrl = (Control)Session["ctrl"];
        printHelper.PrintWebControl(ctrl);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a using C2Project; statement on top of your webForm.print.aspx.cs file?

Answer (score 0):

Add reference to your file, in `webForm print.aspx.cs` class (on top of your page):

```
using C2Project;
```

make your class static (its not really needed):

```
public static class PrintHelper
{
   public static void PrintWebControl(Control ctrl)
   {
       PrintWebControl(ctrl, string.Empty);
   }
   . . .
}
```

Comment: can you provide whole part of your usage?